# What does from __future__ import absolute_import actually do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-2.5

I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22679558/2588818) a question regarding absolute imports in Python, which I thought I understood based on reading [the Python 2.5 changelog](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) and accompanying [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). However, upon installing Python 2.5 and attempting to craft an example of properly using `from __future__ import absolute_import`, I realize things are not so clear.

Straight from the changelog linked above, this statement accurately summarized my understanding of the absolute import change:

> Let's say you have a package directory like this:
>
> ```
> pkg/
> pkg/__init__.py
> pkg/main.py
> pkg/string.py
> ```
>
> This defines a package named `pkg` containing the `pkg.main` and `pkg.string` submodules.
>
> Consider the code in the main.py module. What happens if it executes the statement `import string`? In Python 2.4 and earlier, it will first look in the package's directory to perform a relative import, finds pkg/string.py, imports the contents of that file as the `pkg.string` module, and that module is bound to the name `"string"` in the `pkg.main` module's namespace.

So I created this exact directory structure:

```
$ ls -R
.:
pkg/

./pkg:
__init__.py  main.py  string.py
```

`__init__.py` and `string.py` are empty. `main.py` contains the following code:

```
import string
print string.ascii_uppercase
```

As expected, running this with Python 2.5 fails with an `AttributeError`:

```
$ python2.5 pkg/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print string.ascii_uppercase
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
```

However, further along in the 2.5 changelog, we find this (emphasis added):

> In Python 2.5, you can switch `import`'s behaviour to absolute imports using a `from __future__ import absolute_import` directive. This absolute-import behaviour will become the default in a future version (probably Python 2.7). **Once absolute imports are the default, `import string` will always find the standard library's version.**

I thus created `pkg/main2.py`, identical to `main.py` but with the additional future import directive. It now looks like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import string
print string.ascii_uppercase
```

Running this with Python 2.5, however... fails with an `AttributeError`:

```
$ python2.5 pkg/main2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main2.py", line 3, in <module>
    print string.ascii_uppercase
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
```

This pretty flatly contradicts the statement that `import string` will **always** find the std-lib version with absolute imports enabled. What's more, despite the warning that absolute imports are scheduled to become the "new default" behavior, I hit this same problem using both Python 2.7, with or without the `__future__` directive:

```
$ python2.7 pkg/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print string.ascii_uppercase
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'

$ python2.7 pkg/main2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main2.py", line 3, in <module>
    print string.ascii_uppercase
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
```

as well as Python 3.5, with or without (assuming the `print` statement is changed in both files):

```
$ python3.5 pkg/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(string.ascii_uppercase)
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'

$ python3.5 pkg/main2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main2.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(string.ascii_uppercase)
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
```

---

I have tested other variations of this. Instead of `string.py`, I have created an empty module -- a directory named `string` containing only an empty `__init__.py` -- and instead of issuing imports from `main.py`, I have `cd`'d to `pkg` and run imports directly from the REPL. Neither of these variations (nor a combination of them) changed the results above. I cannot reconcile this with what I have read about the `__future__` directive and absolute imports.

It seems to me that this is easily explicable by [the following](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) (this is from the Python 2 docs but this statement remains unchanged in the same docs for Python 3):

> #### sys.path
>
> (...)
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, **which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first.**

So what am I missing? Why does the `__future__` statement seemingly not do what it says, and what is the resolution of this contradiction between these two sections of documentation, as well as between described and actual behavior?

Comment: **See also:** https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The changelog is sloppily worded. `from __future__ import absolute_import` does not care about whether something is part of the standard library, and `import string` will not always give you the standard-library module with absolute imports on.

`from __future__ import absolute_import` means that if you `import string`, Python will always look for a top-level `string` module, rather than `current_package.string`. However, it does not affect the logic Python uses to decide what file is the `string` module. When you do

```
python pkg/script.py
```

`pkg/script.py` doesn't look like part of a package to Python. Following the normal procedures, the `pkg` directory is added to the path, and all `.py` files in the `pkg` directory look like top-level modules. `import string` finds `pkg/string.py` not because it's doing a relative import, but because `pkg/string.py` appears to be the top-level module `string`. The fact that this isn't the standard-library `string` module doesn't come up.

To run the file as part of the `pkg` package, you could do

```
python -m pkg.script
```

In this case, the `pkg` directory will not be added to the path. However, the current directory will be added to the path.

You can also add some boilerplate to `pkg/script.py` to make Python treat it as part of the `pkg` package even when run as a file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = 'pkg'
```

However, this won't affect `sys.path`. You'll need some additional handling to remove the `pkg` directory from the path, and if `pkg`'s parent directory isn't on the path, you'll need to stick that on the path too.

Comment: OK, I mean, I get that. That's exactly the behavior my post is documenting. In the face of that, though, two questions: (1.) If "that's not exactly true", why do the docs categorically say it is? and, (2.) How, then, do you `import string` if you accidentally shadow it, at least without rifling through `sys.modules`. Isn't this what `from __future__ import absolute_import` is intended to prevent? What does it do? (PS, I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: Aye, that was me (downvote for 'not useful', wasn't for 'wrong').  It's clear from the bottom section the OP understands how `sys.path` works, and the actual question hasn't been addressed at all.  That is, *What does `from __future__ import absolute_import` actually do?*

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: 1) The changelog is loosely-worded and non-normative. 2) You stop shadowing it. Even rifling through `sys.modules` won't get you the standard-library `string` module if you shadowed it with your own top-level module. `from __future__ import absolute_import` isn't meant to stop top-level modules from shadowing top-level modules; it's supposed to stop package-internal modules from shadowing top-level modules. If you run the file as part of the `pkg` package, the package's internal files stop showing up as top-level.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Answer revised. Is this version more helpful?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, thank you. I have upvoted it. You're probably right that this confusion is entirely due to the wording of the changelog. This problem is largely theoretical to me, since I never really used Python 2.5 and I am careful not to create these situations (naming local modules something I might import from the std lib).

Comment: I tried `python -m pkg/main.py`, it show that `Import by filename is not supported`. why?

Comment: @storen: Assuming `pkg` is a package on the import search path, that should be `python -m pkg.main`. `-m` needs a module name, not a file path.

Answer (score 55):

The difference between absolute and relative imports come into play only when you import a module from a package and that module imports an other submodule from that package. See the difference:

```
$ mkdir pkg
$ touch pkg/__init__.py
$ touch pkg/string.py
$ echo 'import string;print(string.ascii_uppercase)' > pkg/main1.py
$ python2
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 18:02:08) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg.main1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pkg/main1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import string;print(string.ascii_uppercase)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
>>> 
$ echo 'from __future__ import absolute_import;import string;print(string.ascii_uppercase)' > pkg/main2.py
$ python2
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 18:02:08) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg.main2
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>>>
```

In particular:

```
$ python2 pkg/main2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkg/main2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import;import string;print(string.ascii_uppercase)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase'
$ python2
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 13 2014, 18:02:08) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pkg.main2
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>>> 
$ python2 -m pkg.main2
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Note that `python2 pkg/main2.py` has a different behaviour then launching `python2` and then importing `pkg.main2` (which is equivalent to using the `-m` switch).

If you ever want to run a submodule of a package always use the `-m` switch which prevents the interpreter for chaining the `sys.path` list and correctly handles the semantics of the submodule.

Also, I much prefer using explicit relative imports for package submodules since they provide more semantics and better error messages in case of failure.

Comment: So essentially it only works for a narrow case where you've avoided the "current directory" problem? That seems to be a much weaker implementation than is described by PEP 328 and the 2.5 changelog. Do you believe the documentation is inaccurate?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Actually what *you* are doing is the "narrow case". You launch only a single python file to be executed, but this may trigger hundreds of imports. Submodules of a package simply shouldn't be executed, that's all.

Comment: why  `python2 pkg/main2.py` has a different behaviour then launching python2 and then importing pkg.main2?

Comment: @storen That's because the behaviour with relative imports changes. When you launch `pkg/main2.py` python (version 2) does **not** treat `pkg` as a package. While using `python2 -m pkg.main2` or importing it *do* take into account that `pkg` is a package.