# Cannot importe module in a folder created mannually

Tags: python, django

I come from Rails and started with Django projects.

I want to create a folder services (like rails services) that will contain classes that consume from an API and save the data retrieved in our database, in fact, those are jobs that are executed sometimes per day.

I created a folder manually called services into app.
The structure:

```
- root
  - app
    - services
      - job_1.py
    - migrations
    __init__.py 
    models.py
    apps.py
    ...
```

I created the folder manually and added a file call job_1.

The problem is that I need to import a model from job_1.py but I can't because I am getting the error : "ImportError: No module named app.models"
Note that I tried to import the models from the migrations and there is no problem.

Two questions :

1- It's corect to create a folder services manually? (I added the `__init__.py`)

2- Why I am getting this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python

Comment: I've already seen it, though, it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Even the services module needs to have __init__.py, only then python will treat it as directory containing job_1 package. Try it in a shell initially, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following two things:

1. make sure there is an `__init__.py` in the `services` directory and
2. try it with [`from __future__ import absolute_imports`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743880/what-does-from-future-import-absolute-import-actually-do)

   Essentially, you could be running into an issue where you are trying to import a “module from a package and that module imports an other submodule from that package.”

Comment: 1- I created the __init__.py manually (I mean creating a new empty file and named it).