# Package Pathing Errors in Python

Tags: python, package, python-import

So I am working on implementing a file structure to my Python and am having an error with doing imports.  The file structure looks something like this:

```
Dirs(Folder)
   ╘ run.py
     Vers(Folder)
        ╘ __init__.py
          1_1(Folder)
             ╘ Main.py
               secondary.py
               __init__.py
          1_2(Folder)
             ╘ Main.py
               secondary.py
               __init__.py
```

This is the contents of `run.py`

```
import importlib
print("This is the main module")
A = importlib.import_module(str("Vers.1_1.Main"))
A.start()
B = importlib.import_module(str("Vers.1_2.Main"))
B.start()
```

Each `Main.py` and `secondary.py` contain code that is the same except for the version number in the print statements, which is changed depending on the version number of the folder they are in.

```
Main.py

import secondary
class start():
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is version 1.2 main")
        secondary.start()

secondary.py

class start():
    def __init__(self):
        print("This is version 1.1 secondary")
```

This is the output I get when I execute `run.py`

```
This is the main module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "Dirs\Vers\1_1\Main.py", line 1, in <module>
import secondary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'secondary'
```

So from my understanding, `run.py` is able to successfully find and attempt to import `Main.py` from the `1_1` Folder.  However, when executing the `Main.py` file, it is unable to see that `secondary.py` is in the same directory to import it.  I've tried looking for how to fix this problem, but I really don't know what my issue is.  Is how I am attempting to set up packages wrong?  If so what do I need to change in order to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use

```
from . import secondary
```

Longer version: It looks like you assume Python 2 *relative import* semantics, when this is Python 3 with *absolute import* semantics. Have a look e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743880/what-does-from-future-import-absolute-import-actually-do/33744115#33744115) for a more detailed explanation.

If you do

```
import secondary
```

this is an absolute import, and thus is **not** resolved relative to the current package, but rather from `sys.path`.

When you execute `run.py` as a Python script (not as a module with `-m`), the directory the script resides in gets added to `sys.path` automatically, which is why importing `Vers.1_1.Main` works, but `import secondary` does not.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is probably my best solution since I don't want to have to modify all the import statements every time I great a new version directory :P

Comment: @Skitzafreak ... which is exactly one reason why there are those nice explicit relative imports ;-).

Comment: One question though.  Let's say I had an import like `from Mod import ClassA`.  How would I change that to the `from . import` notation?  Does `from . import Mod.ClassA` work?

Comment: @Skitzafreak `from .Mod import ClassA`. `from ... import` only allows you to import submodules directly, not as submodules (unless the outer module does that for you).

Answer (score 0):

After the import your code is executing under `Dirs`, where there is no secondary module to import

Change

```
import secondary
```

in `Main.py`

to

```
import Vers.1_1.secondary
```

and to

```
import Vers.1_2.secondary
```

in the other `Main.py`