# Django hot reload only working on certain files

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have this weird issue where not all file edits are being picked up by the hot reloader for Django.

I have this structure:

```
/
  app/ ... apps in here.
  config/settings.py
  manage.py
```

Now, any changes to config/settings.py or manage.py will result in the django runserver reloading.

But any changes to files inside app/... don't trigger a reload - I have to go and add a newline to manage.py and save (quite irritating).

Any ideas why this might be?

At first I thought it was a docker thing, and it was only picking up files in the base dir, but then changes to config/settings.py also trigger the reload, so clearly it can see deeper.

EDIT: Addition info

Django 3.2, PyCharm, MacOS - yes, all apps are in INSTALLED_APPS

I have another project that has the EXACT same structure and for some reason it works... I'm really stumped.

EDIT adding dc and dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements /requirements
ARG pip_requirement_file

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libjpeg62-turbo-dev zlib1g-dev gcc ca-certificates gcc postgresql-client sed xmlsec1 pax-utils && apt-get clean

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/$pip_requirement_file \
    && find /usr/local \
    \( -type d -a -name test -o -name tests \) \
    -o \( -type f -a -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' \) \
    -exec rm -rf '{}' +

# Copy requirements and install local one
RUN rm -rf /requirements

COPY ./compose/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./compose/django/start-server.sh /start-server.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-server.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-server.sh

# Very specifically copy the files we want to avoid bloating the image.
COPY ./manage.py /app/

COPY ./app/ /app/app/
COPY ./admin_static/ /app/admin_static/
COPY ./config/ /app/config/
COPY ./database/ /app/database/

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/start-server.sh"]
```

docker compose

```
services:
  django:
    container_name: django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
      args:
        pip_requirement_file: local.txt
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
```

Comment: Some questions: 1. What version of Django are you using? 2. What editor/IDE are you using to edit the files? 3. What operating system are you using?

Comment: do you have your app in the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: ^ - also, do you have many apps in the `app` folder? typically django structure is to have each individual app folder on the same level as manage.py

Comment: I've added details

Comment: Hi, Trent! How do you actually run the Django server?

Comment: How your Django server is actually started should be in the _./compose/django/start-server.sh_ file. Also the _apps.py_ might be interesting. How are you actually doing changes, and how do you want them to take affect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to thank everyone for trying to help me solve this riddle that has been doing my head in.

I decided to strip both projects (old and new) back to see why the old worked and the new doesn't.

This is what was different.

Inside config/**init**.py on the old project, this line exists:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

Inside the new project, this was missing.

When I add this in, hot reloading starts working for all files inside app/* ?????

It's working, but honestly, I have no idea why that would make a difference.

Comment: See [What does from __future__ import absolute_import actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743880/what-does-from-future-import-absolute-import-actually-do) It seems you have some issue where your app probably shadows some builtin, you should give more information in your question so it is a [mre] currently it is not reproducible.

Comment: You're right... Up until now I didn't have an MRE

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what the issue is, but offering this answer with a couple of things you can try:

1. There are [reports](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30323) that Pycharm will sometimes cause problems if it has been configured not to update the timestamps of files when saving them (there is a [Preserve files timestamps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-deployment-options.html) setting to control this) which you could try toggling. An easy way to verify if this is the issue is to try editing a file with a different editor (or `touch` the file) and see if that triggers a reload - if it does then the issue is PyCharm.

   Note that the default `StatReloader` will not work if file timestamps don't change.
2. Try installing `pywatchman` and the Watchman service, as mention [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver), which provides a much more efficient way to watch for changes than `StatReloader` which simply polls all files for changes every second - if it's a large project it may be that the `StatReloader` is just taking too long to spot changes.