# Can I safely remove from __future__ import absolute_import in python 3 files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project that used to use python 2, but does not anymore.

I see many lines of code like these :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

**Can I safely remove them all ?**

From what I read, it seems it was only used in python 2 to mimic Python 3 behavior

CF linked question :
[What does from __future__ import absolute_import actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743880/what-does-from-future-import-absolute-import-actually-do)

As well [this source](https://www.twobraids.com/2020/01/from-future-import-absoluteimport.html) :

> Using the absolute_import line in Python 2 changes the search strategy
> to mimic the Python 3 search strategy

Comment: Do you have automated tests to check that your code still works as you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only feature that requires using the future statement is
> `annotations` (see PEP 563).
>
> All historical features enabled by the future statement are still
> recognized by Python 3. The list includes `absolute_import`, `division`,
> `generators`, `generator_stop`, `unicode_literals`, `print_function`,
> `nested_scopes` and `with_statement`. **They are all redundant because they
> are always enabled, and only kept for backwards compatibility.**
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#future-statements

So, yes, you can safely remove it for Python 3 code.