# How to create packages in Python 3? ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I am following the easy guide on the Python Central to create a package for my code:

https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/

So my directory structure is:

```
main.py
pack1/
         __init__.py
         Class1.py
```

In the `main.py` file I import and use `Class1` as:

```
from pack1 import Class1
var1 = Class1()
```

In the `__init__.py` file I have written:

```
import Class1 from Class1
```

I followed the guide exactly and still get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Class1' (in __init__.py)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python 3 has [absolute imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678919/what-is-absolute-import-in-python).  Change your `__init__.py` to :

```
from .Class1 import Class1
```

The leading dot indicates that this module is found relative to the location of `__init__.py`, here in the same directory. Otherwise, it looks for a standalone module with this name.

[PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) gives all details. Since Python 3.0 this is [the only way](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html):

> #### Removed Syntax
>
> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name`. All `import` forms not starting with `.` are interpreted as absolute imports. (PEP 0328)

The file `Class1.py` contains this code:

```
class Class1:
    pass
```

Comment: Okay, now I get the error: TypeError 'module' object is not callable, for the line where I create the object: var1 = Class1().

Comment: Are your sure  your  `__int__.py` contains: `from .Class1 import Class1`?

Comment: Ah sorry, it seems i got the error inside Class1's constructir where I create an object of Class2 which is in the same package. But It was solved by importing Class2 into Class1 with the leading dot notation: from .Class2 import Class2. Thanks!!