# Getting Error Attempting to Debug Python Azure Function - attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I need to be able to debug an Azure function that was written in Python. I am just starting to learn Python, so I apologize if this is overly simplistic. I do not understand why I am getting this error `attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

I am using `VS Code` and a Python extension to debug. My project is organized as follows:

```
/folder1 // the following files are in folder1
.funcignore
host.json
proxies.json
requirements.txt

/folder1/subfolder1 // the following files are in subfolder1
__init__.py
function.json
host.json
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
```

function.json

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [{
            "authLevel": "function",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods": [
                "post",
                "get"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/launch.json

```
{    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/settings.json

```
{
    "azureFunctions.projectSubpath": "folder1"
}
```

**init**.py

```
import logging
import sys, os, json

import azure.functions as func
from datetime import datetime
from . import file1 as foo
from . file2 import *
```

The error, `attempted relative import with no known parent package` happens on the line `from . import file1 as foo` and line `from . file2 import *`.

This function works well on Azure. It is only an issue when trying to run locally. I have read post after post saying that `you're not supposed to use relative imports when running your script as the main module.` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73434418/1561777) for example. That post also states that the simplest fix is `Be sure that your root folder is in sys.path so that interpreter always finds it. (If not, append it manually)`. But it doesn't describe how to do that.

One thing I should mention is that I installed all of the packages into a virtual environment if that makes a difference. I am also trying to debug with the virtual environment activated.

From the console, if I execute `echo $env:pythonpath`, I get `C:\Users\me\repo\ProjectName\folder1`

I did some reading about `PYTHONPATH`: See [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). I set my PYTHONPATH as
[image: PYTHONPATH]

Where the last folder is equivalent to Folder1 in my example. I also tried it with the SubFolder1. Each time I changed the environment variable, I logged out and back in.

I can make the error go away by getting rid of the dot, which I believe means relative path, but the code works in production and we don't want to change the code to make it work locally.

What is the best and most correct way to fix this issue?

Comment: Which Python version you are using? 3.x?

Comment: I am using version 3.11.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can make the error go away by getting rid of the dot, which I believe means relative path, but the code works in production and we don't want to change the code to make it work locally.

- Make sure the Directory structure are same as per the production. If code is working fine locally without the `.` Make sure files are inside the the subfolder. without `.` is absolute import.
- For reference check this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#import-behavior).

**#My Directory structure :**

```
Pyhton v1/
│
├── HttpTrigger1/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── function.json
│   ├── file1.py
│   └── file2.py
│
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
└── requirements.txt
```

[image]

My code
**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging
from .file1 import hello as foo
from .file2 import *
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.\n{foo()}\n{vivek()}")
```

**`file1.py`:**

```py
def hello():
    return "Hello from file1"
```

**`file2.py`;**

```py
def vivek():
    return "Hello Vivek"

def vaibhav():
    return "Hello Vaiabhav"

def shandilya():
    return "Hello Shandilya"
```

**Environment variables :**
These two path should be available in your path variable

```
C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\
C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\
```

[image]

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got it working finally. I think the problem was that my virtual environment was not setup correctly. I have 2 projects. Both projects were in the same virtual environment. I believe what helped is that I created a separate virtual environment for each project. Basically my folder structure was wrong.